# ZF2 Routing only correctly routes the last module array entry

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2, loading

in `config/application.config.php`

```
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'Album',
        'Action',
    ),
```

In the above case, only `Action` routing works, I can locate the `ActionController` and cast actions from it - however, trying to access the `Album` route results in a 404 for any action.

However, if I remove the `'Action'`, from the array, the `Album` routing works completely fine.

Any ideas?

NOTE: ApplicationController (IndexController) still works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I was being stupid, I still had `album => array()` in my routing config. Fixed this.